# Trouble getting size of an array in a js object inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I want to get the size of some data I am retrieving in my controller - I have tried the following code; both utilizing a new `Object.size` function and attempted to get the `length` property directly through `.length`

```
$scope.book = DataService.getBooks();
console.log($scope.book);

-- this function was only added to try and solve the problem.
Object.size = function(obj) {
var size = 0, key;
for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
}
return size;
};

console.log(Object.size($scope.book['value']))
console.log($scope.book['value'].length)
```

Here is a picture of what is stored in the variable. As you can see the `.value` is clearly an array containing 3 objects and a `length` property - why can I not directly retrieve this?

[image]

Edit: Calling `console.log($scope.book['value'].length)` gives me this type error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $scope.book is a promise, it is likely unresolved on your console.log and give you the type error.

So something like this should solve your problem

`$scope.book.$promise.then(function(){
    console.log($scope.book['value'].length);
});`

The size function is unnecessary and confusing since you are setting it on Object, but trying to get the length of an array.

Comment: The size function was only added to try and solve the problem. Edit: Yep it works, Thanks!

Comment: Just mentioned the size function because it was a bit confusing what the question actually was..Try it now, forgot the $promise